# How come AWS geth can't find peers?

Tags: go-ethereum, peers, aws

I am setting up a geth light client on an AWS EC2 instance. After running geth, the client seems to not be able to discover any peers and remains idle. Running admin.peers in the console shows that there are no active peers. Interestingly, unlike on my laptop geth node, where the output "looking for peers" is printed until a peer is found, on AWS there is simply no output after "http endpoint created". I have already ensured port 30303 is open for the server. What could be causing this lack of output and peers? And how do I get more peers for AWS? Is there a list somewhere that I can use?

Comment: Can you check if the firewall has port 30303 open?